# How to make api request to some server in roku

Tags: ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest, roku, brightscript

I am very much new in working with [roku](http://www.roku.com/developer) and roku specific language( BasicScript ). I need to make api calls to some server to get the channels. I am not understanding how to do it in roku. Please suggest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is the direct way to do it without having to rely on the syntax of the code libraries that are included in your SDK:

Blocking Method (all program execution stops until the URL is retrieved):

```
url="http://myserver.com/anExampleQuery?getmydata&apikey=AX5GZP5LL45D987D0&format=XML"
xfer=createobject("roURLTransfer")
xfer.seturl(url)
data=xfer.gettostring()
```

Non Blocking Method where you can do other things while waiting for data:

```
url="http://myserver.com/anExampleQuery?getmydata&apikey=AX5GZP5LL45D987D0&format=XML"
xfer=createobject("roURLTransfer")
xfer.seturl(url)
port=createobject("roMessagePort")
xfer.setport(port)
timer=createobject("roTimeSpan")
timer.mark()
xfer.asyncgettostring()
while true    
    msg=wait(100,port) '100 millisecond pause
    if type(msg)="roUrlEvent" then

        if msg.getresponsecode()=200 then
            data=msg.getstring()
            headers=msg.getresponseheadersarray()
            exit while
        else
            xfer.asynccancel()
        end if
    else
        print "do something useful while we wait for data"   
    end if
    if timer.totalmilliseconds() > 500 then
        ?"timeout exceeded"
        exit while
    end if
end while
print "***************HEADERS******************"
for each header in headers
print header
end for
print "***************DATA*********************"
print data
print "****************************************"
```

Comment: I am getting following Error BRIGHTSCRIPT: ERROR: roUrlTransfer: class PLUGIN|MARKUP on thread RENDER:

Comment: Hello, @alphablender I required to display a dialog in `xfer.asynccancel()` Block, But Task node doesn't Support Dialog. Is there any way to display for dialog. I tried so much way using getparent() But not displaying yet.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya best would be if you create a new question, short answer is use an observer for the a field updated by the task node to toggle the dialog on or off.

Answer (score 0):

```
http=NewHttp("http://server address")
rsp = http.GetToStringWithRetry()
print rsp 'To check the response text from server
```

Comment: This only works if you include the one of the URL utilties file from your SDK, for example url.brs from the TwitterOauth example. url.brs is a library of brightscript functions wrapping the roURLTransfer object, which adds a tiny bit of overhead in terms of execution time.