# ROKU-Using urlTransfer to Call Script File

Tags: url, roku, brightscript

Not sure how Roku and Brightscript actually works. I need to call a script file just before the channel starts to stream.  The script file will convert the stream on fly. I asked how to do this in Roku forum and was told to use urlTransfer. Well, the sdk gives little help that I can see when explaining how to. I ran across this post on stackoverflow:
[How to make api request to some server in roku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431148/how-to-make-api-request-to-some-server-in-roku)

It gives a good example which I think I understand. My confusion comes in where and how the function is called. It has to happen right before the video url is called so the conversion can start.
Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using roVideoPlayer then just before you call the play function and if you are using roVideoScreen then just before the show function.
**Example snippet:**

**roVideoPlayer** 
player=CreateObject('roVideoPlayer')
 * Your code to add content for the player
 * Your call to script
 player.play()

**roVideoScreen** 
player=CreateObject('roVideoScreen')
 * Your code to add content for the player
 * Your call to script
player.show()

Hope this helps

Comment: hello, it is possible in Roku to switching a screen means one screen button click to navigate another screen.

Comment: Roku uses SceneGraph concepts, which is different than the older sdk used back around 2012. In ScenGraph Concepts, different screnes are managed through components ( use of Group, LayoutGroup etc) and then ordering them in z-index or changing the components visibility. Check this link https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/core-concepts/controlling-screen-program-flow.md an the example's in the same page. The example should help you understand the concept.